# JavaFX TableView custom row style on double click

Tags: css, javafx

I have a TableView in my JavaFX application.
I would like to style differently row when it is double-clicked on it, and differently when it is single-clicked.

Here is what I achieve:

```
final PseudoClass doubleClickPseudoClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("new");
setRowFactory(tableView -> {
    final TableRow<Bean> row = new TableRow<Bean>();
    row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (! row.isEmpty())) {
            row.pseudoClassStateChanged(doubleClickPseudoClass, true);
    });

    return row;
});
```

However, when the user doubles click on every new row, I want all previously double-clicked rows to be styled without applying "new" class:
row.pseudoClassStateChanged(doubleClickPseudoClass, false);

How can I do that?
Now I have cumulative styled all rows as they are double-clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `TableRow`s to store the state themselves since new items may be assigned to a `TableRow` instance. Instead use a property to store the item double-clicked item and use a listener for styling the rows:

```
final ObjectProperty<Bean> doubleClickedObject = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
setRowFactory(tableView -> new TableRow<Bean>() {
    private void updateStyle() {
        pseudoClassStateChanged(doubleClickPseudoClass, !isEmpty() && doubleClickedObject.get() == getItem());
    }

    private final InvalidationListener listener;

    {
        listener = o -> updateStyle();
        doubleClickedObject.addListener(new WeakInvalidationListener(listener));

        setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (!isEmpty() && event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                doubleClickedObject.set(getItem());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Bean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        updateStyle();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It works now, i just had to set changeListener on doubleClickedObject and call updateStyle();